# Login and accessing wikipedia API using pywikipedia

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, pywikibot

I am new to python.
I have a task to access wikipedia.
For this I am using the client [pywikipedia](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPywikipediabot) to access mediawiki api.
WHen I am running login.py it is asking me password. how will I get the password?
has somebody worked on pywikipedia tool?
Any suggestion which client can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pywikipedia asks for your Wikipedia login. You can register an account on Wikipedia, as well as any other MediaWiki wiki, to assign your edits. When you use pywikipedia, it usually expects you to use an account (instead of editing anonymously).

Note that some wikis may have special requirements for people to run bots; some might require you to ask for a bot status first, and some might disallow you to make changes via the API (I don’t exactly know how it is done on Wikipedia, you’ll need to find that out yourself).

For configuration, please take a look at the `user-config.py` file inside of the pywikipedia directory. This is where you define on which wiki you are working on (`family`), and also which username to use (`usernames[familyname][language]`).

See also:

- [pywikipediabot on Meta](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Pywikipediabot)
- [pywikipediabot basics on Meta](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Pywikipediabot/Basic_use)
- [Wikipedia:Bots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBots) for general information about using bots on Wikipedia
- [Wikipedia:Bot policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBot_policy) for rules your bot is required to follow

Comment: On the English Wikipedia, you must apply at [WP:BRFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:BRFA) and get approved before running a bot which edits pages. Smaller wikis are usually more relaxed and only require preregistration if your bot edits frequently or does controversial things.

Comment: Thanx guys I am able to login now but as I am not approved there is a prompt:

* Your username is not listed on [[[u'Wikipedia:Bots/Status', 'BotS']]]. * Please make sure you are allowed to use the robot before actually using it!

I will only be most of the time getting data for viewing. Shall I still get Bots/Requests for approval ??

Comment: In doubt: Yes, ask them about it. They’ll probably tell you what to do, so you can access the wiki from your bot without such errors.

Comment: Is pywikipedia only for making edits ?  I want to just retrive the content of page is that possible and for putting the new data we use page.put()  what funtion is used to see the content of page on our console

Comment: No, pywikipediabot is a general bot framework for nearly all tasks about MediaWiki. But editing is still a core part of it. You can get the page content using `page.get`. Take a look at the linked manuals on pywikipediabot to get some good examples on how to use it.